# Anonymous letter from somewhere sometime today

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> Not many know of me, and even less have touched what is mine. 
>   A lonely fella I am, like being the smallest pebble in the puddle, 
>   Unless you ask the bishop, he owns the title, according to a beaver's idea. 
>   Reached I am by twelve shiny points, across that much and two more... 
>   Almost exposed myself by now, but before you find me, you should know, 
>   That robbing me of my salty gold, is viable no more for some time now. 
>   And as a goodbye, I thank you for this conversation, and may God's will be above all!
>
> P.S. You may want to rob the the Devil instead, just break the king's seal.

I hope you'll find this interesting enough. Don't know what else to say, time will tell.

The answer is a single word, who or what is the author of this letter, which was sent to you?

**Hint:**

> The answer is a [*geographical place*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/people-and-places/geographical-places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this letter describes

> [Nauru](http://wikitravel.org/en/Nauru)

Not many know of me, and even less have touched what is mine.

> Nauru is the least visited country in the world with less than 200 tourist visits in 2011.

A lonely fella I am, like being the smallest pebble in the puddle,

> Nauru is a remote island in the South Pacific - it is the world's smallest island (pebble/rock) nation.

Unless you ask the bishop, he owns the title, according to a beaver's idea

> [Bishop Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop_Rock,_Isles_of_Scilly) of the Isles of Scilly is the smallest island with a structure. This is from the Guinness World Records, which started as Hugh Beaver's idea.  Thanks OP for this!

Reached I am by twelve shiny points, across that much and two more...

> On its [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Nauru), Nauru is symbolized by a 12-pointed star, each point representing one of the 12 indigenous tribes on the island.
>  That much and two more = 12 + 2 = 14 refers to the fourteen districts the island is divided into.

Almost exposed myself by now, but before you find me, you should know,

> Note the acrostic down the left side the first four lines begin: NAUR

That robbing me of my salty gold, is viable no more for some time now.

> The salty gold is the Phosphate (chemically a salt) deposits originating from sea bird droppings.
>
>  Nauru had the highest per-capita income of any sovereign state in the world during the late 1960s and early 1970s.  The primary phosphate reserves were exhausted, crashing the local economy in the process.

And as a goodbye, I thank you for this conversation, and may God's will be above all!

> Nauru's official motto is  "God's will first"

P.S. You may want to rob the the Devil instead, just break the king's seal.

> The Devil refers to Morocco. Its flag is red and it has a five pointed star, which refers to the pentagram. Red color and pentagram associate to the devil. Morocco has the world's biggest phosphate reserve in the world, and is second in its production (behind China). If you were planning a phosphate heist, this is the place to rob instead. The king's seal refers to the five-pointed star actually representing the Seal of Solomon (King Solomon). Thank you, Vepir, for this!

Comment: That's correct! I'll explain then all the lines in few comments? **First two lines** you described correctly; also it is the least visited country in the world with less than 200 tourist visits in 2011. (35000 visits in North Korea in the same year, for comparison), hence lonely and not known. Pebble or rock refers to it being an island, then the bishop in the **third line refers** to the Bishop Rock, smallest island with a structure on it according to the Guinness WR book, which started as Hugh Beavers idea (he is the founder of Guinness Book of Records), hence according to a beaver.

Comment: The **second part of the fourth line** refers to the ("that much and two more" = 12 + 2 = 14) fourteen districts the island is divided in ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauru)). The **fifth line** "Almost exposed myself by now" refers to lines before it (what you noticed and written at the end), to the first four lines spelling NAUR in the first letters. You are right about the **sixth line** on the phosphate, which is a salt in chemistry. The **seventh line** is described well, as well.

Comment: @Vepir You may want to add [tag:trivia] and [tag:knowledge] tags too.

Comment: In the **P.S. line**, The Devil refers to Morocco. It's flag is red and it has a five pointed star, which refers to the pentagram. Red color and pentagram of course associate to the devil. Morocco has the worlds biggest phosphate reserve in the world, and is second in it's production (behind China), hence it if you were planning a phosphate heist, this is the place to rob instead. The kings seal, refers to the five pointed star actually representing the Seal of Solomon, king Solomon.

Comment: I was planning to add a hint exactly 24 hours after this was posted, but I guess you got the answer 2 hours earlier! You might want to update the post with the full explanation now.

Comment: @Techidiot I guess you are right.

Comment: Thank you Vepir for this - I feel that I've learned so much today from researching and your full descriptions which I added.

Comment: @Vepir -- it's not much fun and doesn't really give anyone else a chance to answer when you blatantly explain the remaining lines in explicit detail less than 24 hours after you have posted the puzzle. May I suggest instead exposing hints over time or nudging a solution in the right direction.

Comment: @feelinferrety I figured since the answer was already found, but as you said, I could've left the remaining lines to be worked out.