# I need a vacation

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, geography

> Into the water a lion's head spews,
>   a fine city's residents line up in queues.
>
> Middle of the world,
>   an Andean pearl,
>   a high city famous for mountainous views.
>
> Into the ocean the Komo's flow pours,
>   a free city's residents populate the shores.
>
> Pacific nation,
>   of small population,
>   a pleasant isle famous for phosphorus ores.

Where are we? Looking for a one-word answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that we are on Earth? :)

Comment: Why does nobody ever consider the pacific nations of Jupiter...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you thinking of going somewhere around the

> Equator

Into the water a lion's head spews, a fine city's residents line up in queues.

> Singapore lies one degree north of the equator on the coast. Singapore is an anglicisation of siṃha (lion) and pura (city). A national symbol is the the Lion head symbol of Singapore.

Middle of the world, an Andean pearl, a high city famous for mountainous views.

> Quito  is the capital city of Ecuador, and at an elevation of 2,850 metres above sea level, it is the second-highest official capital city in the world and the one which is closest to the equator.

Into the ocean the Komo's flow pours, a free city's residents populate the shores.

> Libreville (free city) is the capital of Gabon. It is a port on the Komo River close to the equator.

Pacific nation, of small population, a pleasant isle famous for phosphorus ores.

> Nauru, formerly known as Pleasant Island, is a phosphate rock island close to the equator.

Comment: This is it :) Nice work.

Comment: @jafe - Hope you get that vacation (except we'd miss your puzzles). I was fortunate for the fourth spot: [Anonymous letter from somewhere sometime today](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52581/anonymous-letter-from-somewhere-sometime-today/52596#52596)